# spyne - generating xsd for requests that does not require explicit statement of namespace for each input parameter

Tags: python, web-services, soap, xsd, spyne

At present, my Spyne-based WSGI application generates XSDs for requests like the following:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:aso="asoapns">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <aso:findSpace>
         <aso:Volume>?</aso:Volume>
         <aso:Area>?</aso:Area>
         <aso:Atmosphere>?</aso:Atmosphere>
         <aso:Location>?</aso:Location>
      </aso:findSpace>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Would it be possible to make the input parameters able to be specified without a namespace specifically? i.e. For example:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:aso="asoapns">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <aso:findSpace>
         <Volume>?</Volume>
         <Area>?</Area>
         <Atmosphere>?</Atmosphere>
         <Location>?</Location>
      </aso:findSpace>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Or is this a natural requirement of a SOAP API?

Answer (score 1):

Specifying 'soft' validation as opposed to 'lxml' in the application specification allows requests to not need specific namespaces listed.

```
application = Application(  [API],
                            tns = soap_namespace,
                            in_protocol=Soap11(validator='soft'),
                            out_protocol=Soap11())
```